# How to setup bazaar on slicehost

Tags: svn, slicehost

I managed to install bazaar on slicehost - but I am not sure how to make the repository web accessible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For read-only repositories, you just need to put the directory containing the .bzr folder in a web-accessible directory.  There is no web server module like subversion uses (though of course mod_dav_svn is what allows for read/write access over HTTP, which Bazaar does not do.

You should create the directory in the web space using

```
bzr init-repo --no-trees directory
```

Then push a local repository to this (using bzr+ssh or sftp).  That will ensure that only the repository files are in the web space and that it is not a full working directory.  If after the push your folder just contains a .bzr folder, you've done it correctly.

You should of course take whatever steps are appropriate to secure / authenticate / log access to the web space.

Answer (score 0):

With ssh.  You can do bzr command ssh://server.com/path/to/repo

This happens automatically since ssh just works.  Just setup keys and such so you can skip out on all passwords and such